# How to invoke BIRT viewer based report display in thymeleaf springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf, birt

Implementing thymeleaf based application to display BIRT report using birt viewer as the parameters used in report aren't same/known to us.
Any leads on implementation methodology or referral links to any working project would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Get the BIRT runtime from the latest snapshot directory [1] and unzip it. Make sure that java is installed and on the path.

Then find a genReport.bat in the report engine directory, open a command window and run it. This will spit out some documentation

To run the sample report, open a command window and run

```
genReport.bat samples\hello_world.rptdesign
```

This will result in a rendered output in the samples directory.

[1] https://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/drops/snapshot/